# Pass array of objects to Spring MVC controller using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have a POJO as follows, it contains a list of other POJOs:

```
public class Commit {

    private long revision;
    private Date date;
    private String author;
    private String comment;
    private String akuiteo;
    private List<ChangedPath> changedPathList = new ArrayList<ChangedPath>();

//Getters, Setters and Constructor following
}
```

My controller expects 3 parameters one of them being an array or a list of Commit:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/selectedCommits",method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public List<Commit> getAllDependentCommits(@RequestParam("branch")String branch,
@RequestParam("tag")String tagName,@RequestParam(value="commits[]") Commit[] commits) throws IOException{
    List<String> changedPaths=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Commit> dependentCommits=UserService.listAllCommits(branch, tagName, commits);
    //UserService.createPatchFromSelectedCommits(branch, tagName, revisions);
    return dependentCommits;
}
```

I have also tried:`List<Commit> commits` instead of `Commit[ ] commits`

I call the controller from a jQuery script using AJAX:

```
$("#buttonCommit").click(function(e){
console.log(branch);
console.log(tag);
console.log(selectedCommits);
$.ajax({
    url:'selectedCommits?branch='+branch+'&tag='+tag,
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'application/json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data:{
        commits:selectedCommits,
    },
    success:function(data){
        alert('wow smth really happened, here is the response : '+data[1]);
        window.selectedCommits=selectedCommits;
        window.dependentCommits=data.dependentCommits;
        console.log(data.dependentCommits);
    }
})
});
```

I have also tried: `commits:JSON.stringify(selectedCommits)`

Every time I get the error:

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException:
Required Commit[] parameter 'commits[]' is not present
```

I have also tested passing an array of Long representing the revisions and it worked, I can manage using it for my services but it would be nicer to have an array of objects. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use

```
@RequestBody List<Commit> commits
```

in your controller instead of

```
@RequestParam(value="commits[]") Commit[] commits
```

Comment: If I use a RequestBody will I have to create an object that holds a branch a tag and a commit list so that I can retrieve all 3 parameters?

Comment: @dannemp no, you don't have to. just replace - and that's all. `@RequestParam` is used to get query parameter from URL and the `@RequestBody ` is used to map request body - everything is simple:)

Comment: @dannemp you can move tagName and branch to your url as query parameters. it is not the best practice here. but if you just want to make it work - this is the simplest way

Comment: Now I get "Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported" as error

Comment: @dannemp try to use contentType: "application/json" in your ajax request

Comment: Now I have a new error: " com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'commits': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null') "
I don't get it, why Spring is not able to correctly deserialize the json...

Comment: @dannemp paste your ajax request somewhere, I'll take a look.

Comment: @dannemp change list to array in controller. due to Java's type erasure jackson won't be able to parse list of specific objects. also you can wrap list in a wrapper class

Comment: I get the same error, could it be the fact that the Commit class also contains a List<> of POJOs?

Comment: @dannemp  don't think so. have you tried JSON.stringify?

Comment: yes, I have tried it, I have checked the http request sent by the client and it is the same, with or without stringify, which is rather strange

Comment: @dannemp and this way too `data: JSON.stringify(selectedCommits)`? if you don't mind you could share the project with me and I could make it work

Comment: I can't share the whole project, I have created a new question that I hope is more clear than this one. [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44756318/how-to-pass-array-of-objects-containing-arrays-of-objects-to-spring-mvc-controll)

Answer (score 0):

In my project what I did is the following (I'll try to adapt my solution to your code):

```
$("#buttonCommit").click(function(e){
//Populate the array with selectedCommits values
var myArray = new Array();

$.ajax({
    url:'selectedCommits',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:{
        branch:branch,
        tag:tag,
        commits:myArray,
    },
    success:function(data){
        alert('wow smth really happened, here is the response : '+data[1]);
        window.selectedCommits=selectedCommits;
        window.dependentCommits=data.dependentCommits;
        console.log(data.dependentCommits);
    }
})
});
```

By doing in this way and without using the `JS stringify` method all works pretty good

Angelo

Comment: I have tried your solution and it doesn't solve the problem. I log both the selectedCommits and myArray to the console and they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
 $.ajax({
        type : "post",
        dataType : 'json', 
        url : 'addAdmin',  
        data : JSON.stringify(selectedCommits)
 })
```

Controller (note it takes a custom String only). Then it uses Jackson to parse the string manually, because Spring won't do it in this case. (Spring will only auto-parse if you're using @ModelAttribute form binding.)

```
@PostMapping("/addAdmin")
public boolean addAdmin(@RequestBody String json) throws Exception {

      String decodedJson = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(json, "UTF-8");
      ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); // This is Jackson
      List<UserRolesGUIBean> userRolesGUIBeans =  jacksonObjectMapper.readValue(
              decodedJson, new TypeReference<List<UserRolesGUIBean>>(){});
      // Now I have my list of beans populated.
}
```