# How to pass array of objects containing arrays of objects to Spring MVC controller using jQuery?

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to send an array of POJOs each containing a list of other POJOs from the client side to a Spring MVC RestController through an AJAX call.

I have the following POJO that is the Commit:

```
public class Commit {

private long revision;
private Date date;
private String author;
private String comment;
private String akuiteo;

private List<ChangedPath> changedPathList = new ArrayList<ChangedPath>();
```

It contains a List of changed paths:

```
public class ChangedPath extends PatchFile {

private char type;
private String copyPath;
```

I have the following Spring controller:

```
@RestController
public class AkuiteoMapController {

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PatchDemoApplication.class.getName());

public AkuiteoMapController() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@RequestMapping(value="/akuiteoMap")
@ResponseBody
public AkuiteoMap getAllCommits(@RequestBody Commit[] commits) throws IOException{
    log.info("inside akuiteoMap");
    AkuiteoMap akuiteoMap=new AkuiteoMap();
    akuiteoMap= UserService.getAkuiteoMap(commits);
    log.info("akuiteo map: "+akuiteoMap);
    return akuiteoMap;
}
```

}

On the client side I try to do the following ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'akuiteoMap',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',// charset=utf-8',
        data:{
            commits:JSON.stringify(commits),
            //commits:commits
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
```

I get the following error:

```
2017-06-26 10:58:40.764  WARN 4788 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] 
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: 
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: 
JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'commits': was expecting ('true', 
'false' or 'null'); nested exception is 
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'commits': 
was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@e57cb2a; line: 1, column: 9]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that's strange but look what I've found, try it: `' "commits" : " '+JSON.stringify(commits)+' " '`. the guy had the similar issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the JSON string as the data which would accept the controller method.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'akuiteoMap',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',,
    data : JSON.stringify(commits),
    // ----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```

Comment: @dannemp it seems to me that we tried this approach but you wrote it hadn't helped you o_0